# what are some of the oldest and most accurate approximations of pi?

Tags: pi

I read that there is a tradition in the Jewish literature of an approximation of pi given in the [prophets](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16883/is-the-passage-describing-an-approximation-of-pi-or-is-it-one-of-the-miracles-of/29995?s=3%7C0.0681#29995) was very accurate ($\frac{3\times111}{106} \approx 3.14150\ldots$ - difference of about $.0026\%$)

I'm curious what is the next ancient (>1000 years) more accurate approximation of Pi?

Comment: Do you mean what is the next more accurate rational approximation?

Comment: The justification for the claim that there was such an approximation is rather shaky, however, and has a distinctly ex post facto appearance.

Comment: I think the nearest one can get in the Old Testament is $3$, which is not particularly impressive.

Comment: @André: There’s an ingenious but rather contorted argument based on Hebrew gematria that the passage in question actually contains the approximation mention in the question: it uses two forms of a word for a length, one evaluating to $111$ and the other to $106$.

Comment: You can find a chronology of approximations [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_computation_of_%CF%80).

Comment: @AndréNicolas - the reasoning is that the approximation of 3 is far too crude given their general level of wisdom and scientific knowledge.  There is another approximation method that uses the width of the wall of the pool and the width of 10 arms-lengths is from the inner wall and the circumference of 30 arms-lengths is from the outer wall - but I haven't done the math.  There are several sources in the Jewish literature which basically talk about pi so it's clear they didn't think it was 3.

Comment: @copper.hat - I am looking for other "old" approximations - ideally from before 1000 years or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_computation_of_%CF%80) given by Brian, Ptolemy obtained $\pi\approx \frac{377}{120}$ in the 2nd century. This is closer to $\pi$ than $\frac{333}{106}$.

$$\frac{377}{120}-\pi \approx 7.4·10^{-5}$$ 
$$\pi-\frac{333}{106} \approx 8.3·10^{-5}$$

The error has an integral formula similar to the one given by Dalzell for $\frac{22}{7}-\pi$ (see [Series and integrals for inequalities and approximations to $\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654104/series-and-integrals-for-inequalities-and-approximations-to-pi)), as well as a corresponding series with constant numerator terms.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{377}{120}-\pi
&=
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{x^5(1-x)^6}{1+x^2}dx \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{7!}{(4k+2)(4k+3)(4k+4)(4k+5)(4k+7)(4k+8)(4k+9)(4k+10)}
\end{align}$$

Ptolemy's approximation is the mediant fraction of $\frac{22}{7}$, given by Archimedes, and $\frac{355}{113}$, from Zu Chongzhi.
$$\frac{22+355}{7+113}=\frac{377}{120}$$

The latter is closer to $\pi$, but it is dated about three centuries later.

Answer (score 2):

According to [wikipedia] the approximation $\frac{22}{7}=3.\overline{142857}$ is known since antiquity, and Archimedes proved it is smaller than $\pi$.

Note that you can obtain  good rational approximations of $\pi$ by using the continued fraction method. write:

$$\pi=3+\{\pi\}=3+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\{\pi\}}}=3+\frac{1}{7+\{\frac{1}{\{\pi\}}\}}$$

Up to now we have the approximation $\frac{22}{7}$ But we can take it a step further:

$$3+\frac{1}{7+\{\frac{1}{\{\pi\}}\}}=3+\frac{1}{7+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\{\frac{1}{\{\pi\}}\}}}}=3+\frac{1}{7+\frac{1}{15+\{\frac{1}{\{\frac{1}{\{\pi\}}\}}\}}}\}$$

Which gives us the approximation $\frac{333}{106}=3.1\overline{4150943396226}$

The next approximation would be $\frac{355}{113}$ and after that we have $\frac{103993}{33102}=3.1\overline{415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316}$

---

Now that I look at it the fraction you gave is $\frac{333}{106}$, which is also one of the convergents of $\pi$. It can be proven that the best approximations (The ones that give the best size of denominator vs accuracy ratio are all convergents.)

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you very much. :)