# Series and integrals for inequalities and approximations to $\pi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, definite-integrals, pi, diophantine-approximation

> **Fundamentals**

Two beautiful expressions that relate $\pi$ to its convergents are Dalzell integral

$$\frac{22}{7}-\pi=\int_0^1\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx$$

(see [Why do we need an integral to prove that $\frac{22}{7} > \pi$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456033/why-do-we-need-an-integral-to-prove-that-frac227-pi))

and the following equivalent form of Lehmer series
$$\pi-3=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{24}{(4 k+1) (4 k+2) (4 k+4)}$$

(see http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa27/aa27121.pdf, page 139)

These are direct proofs that $\pi>3$ and $\frac{22}{7}>\pi$, because of the positiveness of the closed form under the summation and the integral, respectively.

> **Symmetry**

Evaluating Lehmer series leads to the integral
$$\pi-3=\int_0^1 \frac{4x^4(1-x)(2+x)}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}dx$$

Another relationship is given by the integral 
 $$\pi-3=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2 x (1-x)^2}{1+x^2} dx$$

and the series
$$\pi-3=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{24}{(4k+2)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+6)}$$

[A series to prove $\frac{22}{7}-\pi>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652812/a-series-to-prove-frac227-pi0) is given by
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{240}{(4k+1)(4k+2)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+6)(4k+7)}=\frac{22}{7}-\pi$$

which generalizes to 
$$\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{240}{(4k+1)(4k+2)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+6)(4k+7)}=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{4n}(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx$$

With this expression approximating fractions from the integrals in the RHS may be computed sequentially by adding the next term in the series.

For $n=0$ we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{10}{3}-\pi
&=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{240}{(4k+1)(4k+2)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+6)(4k+7)} \\
&=
\int_0^1 \frac{(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx \\
\end{align}$$

and the same difference may be obtained from a series with three factors in the denominator and its corresponding integral

$$\begin{align}
\frac{10}{3}-\pi
&=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{24}{(4k+4)(4k+6)(4k+7)} \\
&= 
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{4x^3(1-x)(1+2x)}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}dx \\
\end{align}$$

> **More convergents**

For the third convergent, we have Lucas integral and a series
$$\begin{align}
\pi-\frac{333}{106}
&=
\int_0^1 \frac{x^5(1-x)^6(197+462x^2)}{530(1+x^2)}dx \\
&=
\frac{48}{371} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{118720 k^2+762311 k+1409424}{(4 k+9) (4 k+11) (4 k+13) (4 k+15) (4 k+17) (4 k+19) (4 k+21) (4 k+23)} \\
\end{align}$$

(see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1593090/134791)

Finally, Lucas integral for the fourth convergent is
$$\frac{355}{113}-\pi=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^8(1-x)^8(25+816x^2)}{3164(1+x^2)}dx$$
(see http://educ.jmu.edu/~lucassk/Papers/more%20on%20pi.pdf)

> **Q** Is there a series for $\frac{355}{113}-\pi$?

Comment: You seem to be really fascinated by this kind of problems. I enjoy to learn all of that from you. Thanks.

Comment: In what way do the others series correspond to their integrals?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you! They are fascinating and an answer leads to another question...

Comment: @GerryMyerson They evaluate to the same difference, I do not derive them from each other.

Comment: Speaking of symmetry in your nice series, factors in the numerators - they are definitely internally symmetrically balanced; for 22/7 one:  3+17=5+15=7+13=9+11=20                                                                       for 333/106 one:                                            9+23=11+21=13+19=15+17=32

Comment: @Alex Those denominators are symmetrical by construction, maybe other combinations should be investigated. In contrast, Lehmer series seems like it has a (4k+3) _missing_, but I would rather have that numerator for the others... Here is _how_ (4k+3) disappears or divides itself into (4k+2) and (4k+4) http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1639961/134791
In the other series, there are constant numerators after solving the system but before merging: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652812/a-series-to-prove-frac227-pi0 
maybe that is all that can be expected.

Comment: I have no proof but, $\displaystyle \dfrac{355}{113}-\pi=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1489440+10321440k}{1243(4k+13)(4k+15)(4k+17)(4k+19)(4k+21)(4k+23)(4k+25)(4k+27)}$

Comment: @FDP Please write that gem as an answer so you get all the upvotes you deserve. Here is the proof, with the common factor in the numerator out of the sum. Thank you very much!
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(480%2F1243)sum(k%3D0..inf,(3103%2B21503k)%2F((4k%2B13)(4k%2B15)(4k%2B17)(4k%2B19)(4k%2B21)(4k%2B23)(4k%2B25)(4k%2B27)))

Comment: In that case, Jaume, you are not using the word, "corresponding", the way the rest of the world uses it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Now there is a true correspondence, I think:
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1657416/134791
Your comment made me think a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no proof of it, but,

$\displaystyle \dfrac{355}{113}-\pi=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1489440+10321440k}{1243(4k+13)(4‌​k+15)(4k+17)(4k+19)(4k+21)(4k+23)(4k+25)(4k+27)}$

I got this "equality" (Wolfram Alpha confirms it) playing around with lindep function of PARI GP (LLL stuff)

Comment: This is simpler than I was expecting so a similar question asking for a linear numerator for $\pi-\frac{333}{106}$ should be asked...

Comment: Here it is: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656475/a-series-for-pi-frac333106