# Why is $\tan 3 + \pi$ a near-integer?

Tags: trigonometry, approximation, integers

When playing with my calculator I found that
$$\tan 3 + \pi \approx 3$$ Is there a mathematical reason for this?

Comment: The numbers are not *that* close.  $3-\tan(3)-\pi\approx 9.539\cdot 10^{-4}$.  Really, I would think it stranger if there was *not* a number that could get it that close that is easily represented.  "*Is there a mathematical reason for this?*"  Beyond coincidence and the fact that that so happens to be what the value of $\tan(3)$ and $\pi$ happen to be?

Comment: To be honest the statement $x \approx y$ is extremely subjective.  Nonetheless I would encourage you to keep "playing" with the calculator.  If you do you may discover that there are many examples of "strange coincidences."

Comment: Apologizes in advance... $22/7$  is also approximately equal to $\pi$. Is there any mathematical reason for this? Yes, it's close to $\pi$

Comment: @Yeah.. : there are an integral and a series that evaluate to $\frac{22}{7}-\pi$ 
$$\begin{align}\frac{22}{7}-\pi 
&=
\int_0^1\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx \\
&=
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{240}{(4k+1)(4k+2)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+6)(4k+7)}
\end{align}$$

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654104/series-and-integrals-for-inequalities-and-approximations-to-pi 

The integral shows that this difference is small because the numerator is a product of relatively high power of quantities between $0$ and $1$. The series shows that this difference is small because it is a sum of small numbers.

Comment: @Yeah because $\frac{22}{7}$ is one of the convergents of the continued fraction for $\pi$, e.g.  These always form good approximations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expand $\tan (x)$ near $\pi$ I find
$$\tan(x)=(x-\pi)+\frac{1}{3}(x-\pi)^3+O((x-\pi)^5)$$, and $abs(\frac{1}{3}(x-\pi)^3)\left.\right|_{x=3}<0.001$. I hope this might help